# Why infinite sum need to be made sense?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry

For example,the sum in the partition of unity,and the polynomial expression in abstract algebra.[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think that these to examples call for the same explanation. These fragments are insufficient.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Can you explain it one by one?Thanks!

Comment: "These fragments are insufficient" means no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sums with an infinite number of terms (or "series" in more formal terms) need some extra conditions to make sure they are "well behaved". Otherwise you can get paradoxes like the following:

$S = 1 + 1 + 1 + \dots \\ \Rightarrow 2S = 2 + 2 + 2 + \dots \\ \Rightarrow 2S = (1+1) + (1+1) + (1+1) + \dots \\ \Rightarrow 2S = 1 + 1 + 1 + \dots \\ \Rightarrow 2S=S \\ \Rightarrow S = 0$

Typically the extra conditions involve requiring all but a finite number of the terms to be $0$ ("almost all" in mathematical shorthand) or convergence conditions to make sure that the sum has a limiting value.